# Present Perfect for experiences with "live", "study" etc

Tags: present-perfect

I was wondering whether the use of the present perfect tense with verbs such as "live" or "work", which present a more stative state of being, always implies that the action is still true in the present, or perhaps there's no problem with using it for stating that one has had the experience of doing something?

So, in other words, is it possible for me to say:

> I've lived in New York, Boston and Sacramento. I know all about these cities.

Or should I simply stick to the past simple tense, given I no longer live in any of these cities?

Can I state the following, if I don't study this language anymore?

> I've studied French - I know how difficult the sentence order can get.

If I used to work in retail, but no longer do so, can I still use the perfect tense to support my knowledge of dealing with the customers?

> Believe me, I know how to deal with troublesome customers; I've worked in retail.

Comment: You can find sentences like _For the past 40 years, my wife, Lesley, and I have lived in a house we built ourselves, and we grow a lot of our own food on our half-acre of land._ I cannot comment on the difference between that sentence and one using _and I lived in a house we built ourselves_, though.

Comment: Present perfect is quite natural there, and you'd use the simple past only to confine the experience to the past.  I lived there during the ___.  I studied French in school but forget most of what I learned.

Comment: But it only takes a little twist to shift the tense. "I studied French *in school* and..." versus "I've studied French and ..."   Details that are understood to refer to a time in the past tend to be accompanied by the past tense, because  the time elements of a present perfect construction cannot exclude the present.  If "in school" is understood by the speaker to refer to the past then the speaker would chose the past tense